# Formula the conditional probability of mables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a interesting question that need your help. I have two sets A and B. Set A have 10 marbles that numbered from 1 to 10. Set B have 6 marbles that numbered from 1 to 6.

1. Randomly choose $g$ marbels in set A and $h$ marbels in set B. ($g>h$)
   Given the probablity of randomly choose g is $\Omega1$
2. With each marbel in $g$, make a connection (line) from it to $h$ marbels, each marbels in h marbels is connected at least one. Two or more marbels in $g$ marbels can connect to same a marble in $h$ marbles (called repeated connection)

Question: Compute the average number of repeated connection in this even?

This is simple example, given A=10 marbles, B=6 marbles. Choose g=6 marbles from A and h=3 marbles from B. The probability choosing 6 marbels in A is 0.1. The red line is called repeated connection.
[image]

Thank Graham Kemp and David K for your answer. This is other explaination of my problem. However, it is unclear. For example, the average number W is infinite if number of g and h is more than 100.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ be the indicator random variable that marble $i$ in set $B$ has a repeated connection.

$$X=\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i$$

A marble will have a repeated connection of two or more of the $g$ marbles selected from set $A$ connect to it (clearly), so the expected value of $X_i$ is the probability of having that, and the number of connections from the $g$ marbles in $A$ to a specified marble in set $B$ will have a binomial distribution (why?) of $\mathcal {Bin}(g,1/10)$.

We can then use linearity of expectation.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[X_i\mid G=g] & = 1 - {g\choose 0} \frac{9^{g}}{10^g} - {g\choose 1}\frac{9^{g-1}}{10^g}
\\[1ex]
 & = \Box
\\[2ex]
 \mathsf E[X\mid G=g] 
 & = \sum_{i=1}^{10} \mathsf E[X_i\mid G=g]
\\ & = \Box
\\[2ex]
\mathsf E[X] & = \sum_{g=1}^{10} \mathsf E[X\mid G=g]\;\mathsf P(G=g)
\\[1ex] & = \Box
\end{align}$$

Can you complete?

Comment: In the illustrated example, is $X=2$ or is $X=3$?  I thought it should be $3$ according to the problem description, but the $X_i$ seem to be $0,1,1$ with a sum of $2.$  Did I misread someone?

Comment: According to the problem *a* repeated connection is defined as where a marble in B has *two or more* connections leading to it.  So each marble in $B$ can have no connection, one connection, or a repeated connection.

Comment: Thank sir, Could you see the other solution for this problem. Is it similar your solution?

Comment: @GrahamKemp: I think there was some ambiguity in the initial posting of the problem. "The red line is called repeated connection": so do we count the number of blue marbles with red lines (as you did) or just the number of red line segments (as I did)? The addition of a book excerpt helps, although now I'm not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

My reading of your problem statement is that
there is always exactly one connection from each marble in the selected subset of $A$
to any marble in the selected subset of $B.$
Moreover, there is always at least one connection to each marble in the selected
subset of $B.$

In that case, given two subsets and a set of connections that satisfy these
conditions, we can choose $h$ connections, each one connected to a different
marble in the selected subset of $B.$
In your example, the connections drawn in black are a suitable choice of
$h$ connections.
These connections "occupy" exactly $h$ marbles from the subset selected from $A,$
leaving $g -  h$ additional marbles in that subset that are not part of these
chosen connections. But each of those additional marbles has its own connection
to one of the marbles drawn from $B,$ and each of those connections is
necessarily a "repeated" connection.

The number of repeated connections is therefore always exactly $g - h.$
The expected number of repeated connections is $E(g) - E(h),$
but $E(h)$ may be hard to compute.
You seem to be saying that the distribution of $g$ is uniform over the
set of integers $\{1, \ldots, 10\},$
but the probability distribution of $h$ is not clear in the problem statement.

You seem to be requiring $h \geq 1$
(in order to be able to connect each of the $g$ balls to something),
but you also say $g > h,$ which implies $g > 1,$
so perhaps $g$ is not uniformly distributed over $\{1, \ldots, 10\}$ after all?

If you can describe the probability $P(g=i)$ for each integer $i$ in a way
that makes sense within your problem statement, and
if you can describe the conditional probability distribution of $h$
conditioned on each value of $g,$
then you can compute $E(h \mid g=i),$ the conditional expectation of $h$ given that
$g=i$ balls were selected from set $A,$ and you can then compute

$$\begin{eqnarray}E(g - h) &=& \sum_{i=1}^{10} (g - E(h \mid g=i))\,P(g=i) \\
&=& E(g) - \sum_{i=1}^{10} E(h \mid g=i)P(g=i).\end{eqnarray}$$